# Two codes combined into one

Tags: java

I have two codes: an analog clock and a graphical calendar. I would like to put the calendar code into the clock code so that the calendar is under the clock when the program starts. I have tried to do this in several different ways, but the calendar is never visible. The codes are below.

Clock:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension; 
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
class Clock extends JFrame {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(24, 116, 205); 
 public Clock() {
 ClockPanel container = new ClockPanel();
 add(container, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
 setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 setResizable(false);
 pack();
 setVisible(true);
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 new Clock();
 }
}
class ClockPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 Thread t = new Thread(this);
 /** The coordinates used to paint the clock hands. */
 int xHandSec, yHandSec, xHandMin, yHandMin, xHandHour, yHandHour;
 /** The size of the clock. */
 private final int HORIZONTAL_SIZE = 500; private final int VERTICAL_SIZE = 500;
 /** The length of the clock hands relative to the clock size. */
 private final int secondHandLength = HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2 - 50;
 private final int minuteHandLength = HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2 - 70;
 private final int hourHandLength = HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2 - 100;
 /** The distance of the dots from the origin (center of the clock). */
 private final int DISTANCE_DOT_FROM_ORIGIN = HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2 - 40;
 private final int DIAMETER_BIG_DOT = 8;
 private final int DIAMETER_SMALL_DOT = 4;
 
 private final static Color GREY_COLOR = new Color(160,160,160);
 public ClockPanel() {
 setMinimumSize(new Dimension(HORIZONTAL_SIZE, VERTICAL_SIZE));
 setMaximumSize(new Dimension(HORIZONTAL_SIZE, VERTICAL_SIZE));
 setPreferredSize(new Dimension(HORIZONTAL_SIZE, VERTICAL_SIZE));
 setLayout(null);
 t.start();
 }
 /**
 * At each iteration we recalculate the coordinates of the clock hands,
 * and repaint everything.
 */
 public void run(){
 while(true){
 try{
 int currentSecond = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND);
 int currentMinute = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
 int currentHour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR);
 xHandSec = minToLocation(currentSecond, secondHandLength).x;
 yHandSec = minToLocation(currentSecond, secondHandLength).y;
 xHandMin = minToLocation(currentMinute, minuteHandLength).x;
 yHandMin = minToLocation(currentMinute, minuteHandLength).y;
 xHandHour = minToLocation(currentHour * 5 + 
getRelativeHour(currentMinute), hourHandLength).x;
 yHandHour = minToLocation(currentHour * 5 + 
getRelativeHour(currentMinute), hourHandLength).y;
 repaint();
 Thread.sleep(500);
 } catch(InterruptedException ie){
 ie.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 }
 /**
 * Returns how much the hour hand should be ahead
 * according to the minutes value.
 * 04:00, return 0.
 * 04:12, return 1, so that we move the hour handle ahead of one dot. 
 * @param min The current minute.
 * @return The relative offset to add to the hour hand. 
 */
 private int getRelativeHour(int min) {
 return min / 12; }
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
 Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
 g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
 RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
 g2.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
 // Draw the dots
 g2.setColor(GREY_COLOR);
 for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
 
 Point dotCoordinates = minToLocation(i, DISTANCE_DOT_FROM_ORIGIN);
 g2.setColor((i <= Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND)) ? 
Color.black : GREY_COLOR);
 
 if (i % 5 == 0) {
 // big dot
 g2.fillOval(dotCoordinates.x - (DIAMETER_BIG_DOT / 2),
 dotCoordinates.y - (DIAMETER_BIG_DOT / 2),
 DIAMETER_BIG_DOT,
 DIAMETER_BIG_DOT);
 } else {
 // small dot
 g2.fillOval(dotCoordinates.x - (DIAMETER_SMALL_DOT / 2),
 dotCoordinates.y - (DIAMETER_SMALL_DOT / 2),
 DIAMETER_SMALL_DOT,
 DIAMETER_SMALL_DOT);
 }
 }
 // Draw the clock hands
 g2.setColor(Color.black);
 g2.drawLine(HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2, VERTICAL_SIZE / 2, xHandSec, 
yHandSec);
 g2.drawLine(HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2, VERTICAL_SIZE / 2, xHandMin, 
yHandMin);
 g2.drawLine(HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2, VERTICAL_SIZE / 2, xHandHour, 
yHandHour);
 g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 15));
 g.drawString("1", 360, 60);
 g.drawString("2", 440, 140);
 g.drawString("3", 470, 250);
 g.drawString("4", 440, 370);
 g.drawString("5", 360, 450);
 g.drawString("6", 244, 480);
 g.drawString("7", 130, 450);
 g.drawString("8", 50, 370);
 g.drawString("9", 20, 250);
 g.drawString("10", 50, 140);
 g.drawString("11", 130, 60);
 g.drawString("12", 244, 25);
 }
 /**
 * Converts current second/minute/hour to x and y coordinates.
 * @param min The current minute
 * @param radius The radius length 
 * @return the coordinates point
 */
 private Point minToLocation(int timeStep, int radius) {
 double t = 2 * Math.PI * (timeStep-15) / 60;
 int x = (int)(HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2 + radius * Math.cos(t));
 int y = (int)(VERTICAL_SIZE / 2 + radius * Math.sin(t));
 return new Point(x, y);
 } 
}
```

And this is calendar

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Main extends JPanel {
 SimpleDateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
 SimpleDateFormat year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
 SimpleDateFormat day = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
 Date date = new Date();
 public Main() {
 setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 280));
 }
 public void setDate(Date date) {
 this.date = date;
 }
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
 ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
 RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
 g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
 super.paintComponent(g);
 g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 17));
 g.setColor(Color.black);
 g.drawString(month.format(date).toUpperCase(), 34, 36);
 g.setColor(Color.black);
 g.drawString(year.format(date), 235, 36);
 g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 10)); Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
 today.setTime(date);
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(date);
 cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
 cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 1);
 for (int week = 0; week < 5; week++) {
 for (int d = 0; d < 7; d++) {
 g.drawString(day.format(cal.getTime()), d * 30 + 46 + 4, week * 29 + 81 + 20);
 cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
 }
 }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 280));
Main ch = new Main();
ch.setDate(new Date());
frame.getContentPane().add(ch);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to combine your GUI's.

[image: Clock / Calendar]

I modified your `JFrame` code.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AnalogClock extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(24, 116, 205);

    public AnalogClock() {
        setTitle("Clock / Calendar");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        
        ClockPanel container = new ClockPanel();
        add(container, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        CalendarPanel panel = new CalendarPanel();
        panel.setDate(new Date());
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AnalogClock();
            }
        });
    }
}

class ClockPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    /** The coordinates used to paint the clock hands. */
    int xHandSec, yHandSec, xHandMin, yHandMin, xHandHour, yHandHour;
    /** The size of the clock. */
    private final int HORIZONTAL_SIZE = 500;
    private final int VERTICAL_SIZE = 500;
    /** The length of the clock hands relative to the clock size. */
    private final int secondHandLength = HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2 - 50;
    private final int minuteHandLength = HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2 - 70;
    private final int hourHandLength = HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2 - 100;
    /** The distance of the dots from the origin (center of the clock). */
    private final int DISTANCE_DOT_FROM_ORIGIN = HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2 - 40;
    private final int DIAMETER_BIG_DOT = 8;
    private final int DIAMETER_SMALL_DOT = 4;

    private final static Color GREY_COLOR = new Color(160, 160, 160);

    public ClockPanel() {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(HORIZONTAL_SIZE, VERTICAL_SIZE));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(HORIZONTAL_SIZE, VERTICAL_SIZE));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(HORIZONTAL_SIZE, VERTICAL_SIZE));
        setLayout(null);
        t.start();
    }

    /**
     * At each iteration we recalculate the coordinates of the clock hands, and
     * repaint everything.
     */
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                int currentSecond = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND);
                int currentMinute = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int currentHour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR);
                xHandSec = minToLocation(currentSecond, secondHandLength).x;
                yHandSec = minToLocation(currentSecond, secondHandLength).y;
                xHandMin = minToLocation(currentMinute, minuteHandLength).x;
                yHandMin = minToLocation(currentMinute, minuteHandLength).y;
                xHandHour = minToLocation(currentHour * 5 + 
                        getRelativeHour(currentMinute), hourHandLength).x;
                yHandHour = minToLocation(currentHour * 5 + 
                        getRelativeHour(currentMinute), hourHandLength).y;
                repaint();
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns how much the hour hand should be ahead according to the minutes
     * value. 04:00, return 0. 04:12, return 1, so that we move the hour handle
     * ahead of one dot.
     * 
     * @param min The current minute.
     * @return The relative offset to add to the hour hand.
     */
    private int getRelativeHour(int min) {
        return min / 12;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        // Draw the dots
        g2.setColor(GREY_COLOR);
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {

            Point dotCoordinates = minToLocation(i, DISTANCE_DOT_FROM_ORIGIN);
            g2.setColor((i <= Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND)) ? 
                    Color.black : GREY_COLOR);

            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                // big dot
                g2.fillOval(dotCoordinates.x - (DIAMETER_BIG_DOT / 2), 
                        dotCoordinates.y - (DIAMETER_BIG_DOT / 2),
                        DIAMETER_BIG_DOT, DIAMETER_BIG_DOT);
            } else {
                // small dot
                g2.fillOval(dotCoordinates.x - (DIAMETER_SMALL_DOT / 2), 
                        dotCoordinates.y - (DIAMETER_SMALL_DOT / 2),
                        DIAMETER_SMALL_DOT, DIAMETER_SMALL_DOT);
            }
        }
        // Draw the clock hands
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.drawLine(HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2, VERTICAL_SIZE / 2, xHandSec, yHandSec);
        g2.drawLine(HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2, VERTICAL_SIZE / 2, xHandMin, yHandMin);
        g2.drawLine(HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2, VERTICAL_SIZE / 2, xHandHour, yHandHour);
        g.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 15));
        g.drawString("1", 360, 60);
        g.drawString("2", 440, 140);
        g.drawString("3", 470, 250);
        g.drawString("4", 440, 370);
        g.drawString("5", 360, 450);
        g.drawString("6", 244, 480);
        g.drawString("7", 130, 450);
        g.drawString("8", 50, 370);
        g.drawString("9", 20, 250);
        g.drawString("10", 50, 140);
        g.drawString("11", 130, 60);
        g.drawString("12", 244, 25);
    }

    /**
     * Converts current second/minute/hour to x and y coordinates.
     * 
     * @param min    The current minute
     * @param radius The radius length
     * @return the coordinates point
     */
    private Point minToLocation(int timeStep, int radius) {
        double t = 2 * Math.PI * (timeStep - 15) / 60;
        int x = (int) (HORIZONTAL_SIZE / 2 + radius * Math.cos(t));
        int y = (int) (VERTICAL_SIZE / 2 + radius * Math.sin(t));
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
    
}

class CalendarPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    SimpleDateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    SimpleDateFormat year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat day = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
    Date date = new Date();

    public CalendarPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 280));
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(month.format(date).toUpperCase(), 34, 36);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(year.format(date), 235, 36);
        g.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 10));

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        today.setTime(date);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 1);
        for (int week = 0; week < 6; week++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < 7; d++) {
                g.drawString(day.format(cal.getTime()), d * 30 + 46 + 4, 
                        week * 29 + 81 + 20);
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
            }
        }
    }
     
}
```